# Android up navigation behaves differently after locale change from phone settings

Tags: android, android-actionbar, locale, up-navigation

**Activity-A** opens up **Activity-B** which will open up **Activity-C**.
And Activity B is finished after calling `startActivity(intent)`;
Tapping on the actionbar's UP icon we navigate to Activity A under normal circumstances.
But after opening Activity-C if we go to device settings and change the locale, resume the activity-C and tapping on UP icon, Activity B gets loaded again.

How can we achieve the normal behavior even if we alter the locale.

For activity-C in manifest we have specified locale also under `configChanges`

actual value:

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|locale"`

Code Snippet from Activity-B which calls Activity-C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ReaderActivity.this, EPUPReader.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you please add code of Activity B where you start activity C

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya code added

Comment: OK, now your point is you finish your activity B but now you on Activity C but after change Local when you go up it's call again B right.?

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya yes, that's what is happening

Comment: Can you please share you code when you go up..

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya added..

Comment: I need code when you go up from Activity C..

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya am calling onBackPressed() from OnOptionsItemSelected(). code snippet added

Comment: i don't belive it's happen, do one thing please make short demo with 3 activity and share that code i will check and try to find issue., share me google drive link..